# Loading AngularJS Components After the Application is bootstrapped

Tags: angularjs

My application has a main module "myModul" and a main controller "main" which is bind on the body tag.

```html
<body ng-controller="main">
```

Here is the code of my module and controller:

```js
var app = angular.module('myModul', ['ngTouch','widgetContainer']);

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myModul']);
});

app.controller('main', ['$scope', '$http', '$compile', 'loadApps', function($scope, $http, $compile, loadApps) {
    /***** Load all Apps information *****/
    $scope.apps = loadApps.get();
    $scope.apps.then(
        function(result) {
            $scope.apps = result.apps;
        }
    );

    $scope.activateApp = function(obj) {
        if (jQuery('#app' + obj + 'Script').length == 0) {
            jQuery('head').append('<script id="app' + obj + 'Script" type="text/javascript" src="/apps/' + obj + '/scripts/' + obj + '.js"></script>');
        }
        if (jQuery('#app' + obj + 'CSS').length == 0) {
           jQuery('head').append('<link id="app' + obj + 'CSS" rel="stylesheet" href="/apps/' + obj + '/stylesheets/' + obj + '.css">');
        }

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/appMainTemplate',
            params: {name: obj}
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            angular.element('[area="app"]:visible').empty().html($compile(data)($scope));
        });
    } 
}]);
```

The function "activateApp" is triggered by a click on an button. My Node backend for this request is very simple:

```js
app.get('/appMainTemplate', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/apps/' + req.query.name + '/templates/index.html');
});
```

**Now my Question**

I append the send template with this line:

```js
angular.element('[area="app"]:visible').empty().html($compile(data)($scope));
```

How can i define a new modul with controllers, directives etc. in this template and use it? I simplified this template to

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

    app.controller('example123', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.test = 'hello';
    }]);


</script>

<div ng-controller="example123">
    <div>  
        {{test}} <----
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to create a new modul, which i would add to the dependencies to myModul. But even this small controller example123 won't work.I get this error:

Argument 'example123' is not a function, got undefined...

I tried different solutions i read here and on other pages like:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2553-loading-angularjs-components-after-your-application-has-been-bootstrapped.htm

but nothing worked... Truth is, i also don't fully understand the solution.

Mayby someone can fix up my Code or can give a small explanation what to do?

Comment: what is the goal here? why do you need to use JQuery to do anything to the angular scripts?  This feels like a long winded XY question, and it's not really obvious why this is even necessary.

Comment: the goal is to load dynamicly small apps with their own module. The fact i use jQuery to add the template is that i dont know it better. I am not used to use angular... i am not quite sure if loading modules dynamicly is necessary for my usecase, but now i want to know how it works! ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "load small apps"? Do you want to have multiple independent Angular apps running side-by-side on the same page? You should understand though that they would have to occupy non-overlapping DOM subtrees. And, @Claies, it's possible with a manual bootstrap

Comment: I just want to load a module, which i add to the dependencys of my main module. the magic i search is to register the new content to my app. In this small example above, the added controller is not recognised by my application. But i don't want to just add a controller to my main app. i want to add a whole new module. I hope this is understandable...

Comment: Is there something that your modules are doing that makes them not work with Angular's built in Dependency Injection?

Comment: @NewDev ok, yes, "can only run once" was too strong, but I was trying to get across the point that what the OP is asking to do doesn't make much sense in the context of how Angular is designed.

Comment: @Claies, your first comment (which I upvoted) conveys that sentiment properly :)

Comment: LazyLoading components in angularJs should be possible and i don't see a good reason why i shouldn't do it? Modules are one thing, but even the controller example123 is not registered. Do you know how this works?

Comment: if Lazy Loading is your goal, there are angular plugins already created for this purpose ([ocLazyLoad](https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs), for example).  Using JQuery to do this is definitely not recommended.